# Why are CORS header not present in Postman for this simple ASP.NET Core 7 Web API?

Tags: asp.net-core-7.0

I'm testing with the out of the box ASP.NET Core 7 Web API and try to add CORS headers with the AddCors() and UserCors() calls but the headers don't appear in Postman when I test the API call. This is how my program.cs file looks like. Why are these headers not present in the response? Thanks!

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder( args );

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddCors( options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy( builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins( "https://flex.twilio.com" )
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowCredentials()
               ;
    } );
} );

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if ( app.Environment.IsDevelopment() )
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

[image]

I already tried to move the app.UserCors() to different place but according to the documentation the app.UserCors() should be placed after the app.UseHttpsRedirection() call and before the app.UserAuthorisation() call.

Comment: CORS is a browser thing - because browsers send origin headers of the domain making the request with XHRs. If you’re just doing a curl/non-browser-based http request, CORS doesn’t exist as a concept

Comment: I know but I just want to test that Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is added to the response when I'm configuring the ASP.NET Core 7 web api like this. This seems not the case so I'm wondering why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(NB: I don't use ASP.NET. This answer is based on knowing how CORS works and how other libraries that support it handle multiple origins.)

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` only allows a server to specify `*` or a *single* origin.

The name `WithOrigins` implies the support for multiple origins.

To support multiple origins, the server has to examine the `Origin` request header, compare it to the list of allowed origins, and add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header with the *specific* allowed origin if there is a match.

Your screenshot shows that you aren't sending an `Origin` request header from Postman so it won't match any of the allowed origins (you can add `Origin` as `https://flex.twilio.com` in the GUI).

Comment: Thanks, this helped! The headers appear in the response when I add the Origin header in the request. I assumed that the CORS headers would always appear which is not the case.